# Instantiating an object from a class in a header

Tags: c++, header-files, instantiation

I am having a `multiple defintion of Math` error without a file for the cause from the following code:

```
#ifndef SOMEMATH_H
#define SOMEMATH_H

class math{
public:
    int add( int a, int b);
    int divide(int a, int b);
    int subtract(int a, int b);
    int multiply( int a, int b);
}Math;

#endif // SOMEMATH_H
```

Changing `Math` to any other name doesn't change the problem. Instantiating a math object a different way does not fix the problem. Not creating an object of `math` in the header files causes no problems, but I wanted a class created in the header. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header defines an instance of `class math` named `Math`, which is a bad idea because it causes exactly the problem you're experiencing:  If two files include the header, you get two instances with the same name.

You can't safely create an instance of a class in a header like this.  You can *declare* that one exists, and put the actual *definition* in a `.cpp` source file.

This particular class looks like it only has methods, and no actual data associated with it.  That makes me wonder what you're actually trying to do.  If you're just bundling up a set of functions under one name, you might consider a `namespace` instead, or at least making the functions `static` methods under the class:

```
class Math {
public:
    static int add( int a, int b);
    static int divide(int a, int b);
    static int subtract(int a, int b);
    static int multiply( int a, int b);
};
```

or:

```
namespace Math
{
    int add( int a, int b);
    int divide(int a, int b);
    int subtract(int a, int b);
    int multiply( int a, int b);
}
```

Either of those options will save you from needing an instance of a class in order to access the functionality.  You can refer to these functions as `Math::add()`, `Math::divide()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no instantiation in the header.

Long answer: Every cpp in which your file is directly or indirectly included in will have an object `Math` and the linker will complain because it will not be able to choose only one.

A bit more on the subject here, http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/ch7-preview.pdf covering the unix linker, but the idea will remain the same. Basically your example fails on:

> Rule 1: Multiple strong symbols are not allowed

To be honest, I think (but am not sure) that the linker can , in most case, decide that you're creating a reference to the symbol in most case and take one of the ".o" as the real object. But only for 1 library, and thus the bug would rise as soon as you have multiple DLLs. So it's not worth the pain.

So the general rule is "no instantiation in the header". If you want a global variable:

- Instantiate `math Math` in one cpp (even a dedicated one if you want).
- Use "extern math Math" in the other files using it.

But if you can, avoid global objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
// .hpp
#ifndef SOMEMATH_H
#define SOMEMATH_H

class math{
public:
    int add( int a, int b);
    int divide(int a, int b);
    int subtract(int a, int b);
    int multiply( int a, int b);
};

extern math Math;

#endif // SOMEMATH_H

// .cpp

math Math;
```

but it looks like you are trying to mimic Java's Math class. Just use a namespace.